# How to put formatting to Workflow mail SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

How to put any formatting or table to Worklfow mail without put HTML code to properties body mail? Even I put there HTML code the formatting isn't correct...

I will be very gratefull for any help.

Thanks for support,
Andrzej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so far i know white spaces in the html block will cause a email to lose its format.

I found a [good tutorial](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/creating-html-emails-with-spd-workflows.aspx). I hope it will help you

Best regards, Retech

Comment: Links can become outdated with time.  By all means cite your source but also include the content that you wish to submit as the answer.  This ensures that should the content move or site become unavailable, the answer will still have value here on SPSE.